# Send Color of text to android studio like html in c#

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio.
in `c#.net` when I want to change the color of a cell in a repeater without any change in source, I usually use code like this

```
<span style="color:red">hello word</span>
```

and pass it from `SQL database` .on binding repeater it changes.
now I am sending SQL data from the service to an android application.
I don't have any access to its source.
But I want to change cell color in a grid (in the android app) only with pass data from service without any changes in the app source.
like  `<span style="color:red">hello word</span>`  in v.s

Answer (score 0):

In Android, colors are stored as ints. 4 values are stored in it: alpha, red, green, blue.

This is how to convert the values (0 - 255) to a color:

```
void valuesToColor(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue) {
    return (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
}
```

This is how to convert a color to one of the values:

```
int alpha(int color) {
    return color >>> 24;
}

int red(int color) {
    return (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
}

int green(int color) {
    return (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
}

int blue(int color) {
    return color & 0xFF;
}
```

That's probably the expected format of the color as all views with some kind of `setColor()`-method expect this int.